# Selecting maximum date from an XML column

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table named `client` and in that table there is an XML column.

My requirement is to select the maximum `transaction_date` from that XML column.

XML:

```
<detail>
    <transaction_date>2015-06-30</transaction_date>
</detail>
<detail>
    <transaction_date>2015-05-29</transaction_date>
<detail>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is SQL-Server. You can try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<detail>
  <transaction_date>2015-06-25</transaction_date>
</detail>
<detail>
  <transaction_date>2015-06-30</transaction_date>
</detail>
<detail>
  <transaction_date>2015-05-29</transaction_date>
</detail>';

 SELECT MAX(dt.value(N'(transaction_date/text())[1]',N'date')) AS MaxTransactionDate 
 FROM @xml.nodes(N'/detail') AS A(dt)
```

Comment: Can i select this from a particular table?

Comment: @junaib Sure, assuming the XMLs are sitting in a column `TheXML` within a table `TheTable` you could try `SELECT MAX(...) FROM TheTable AS t CROSS APPLY t.TheXML.nodes(...) AS A(dt)`. This might not work, if the provided fragment is just a (nested) part of a bigger XML.